# radio button not refreshing data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

My graph is only showing `data`. it is not showing `data1` and `data 2` when radio button 2 and 3 is being clicked.

vb code:

```
  If RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 1 Then
        ' hidden10.Value = "data"


    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 2 Then
        hidden10.Value = "data1"


    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 3 Then
        hidden10.Value = "data2"


      function draw(d) {

           var testarray = JSON.parse(a);
           var testarray1 = JSON.parse(a1);
           var testarray2 = JSON.parse(a2);
```

javascript code:

```
           var Yaxis = $("#<%=hidden10.ClientID%>").val();


        if (d == 1) {

               var title = Yaxis
                var title = Yaxis
           }


         else if (d == 3) 
           {

               var e = testarray1
               var title = Yaxis

           }
         else if (d == 2) {

               var title = Yaxis
               var title = Yaxis
           }
```

any idea why its not showing the `data1` and `data2`, because it just shows `data` for all 3

postback true, radiobuttons:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="span-third-small">Select Units:</asp:Label>
            <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radioList" ID="RadioButtonList1"
                AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">data</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">data1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">data2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Do you have autopostback="true"?

Comment: and You have your selectedindex changed event?

Comment: what do you mean by changed event

Comment: the graph is not showing the data1 and data2! it shows data for all 3 buttons

Comment: When you select / change radio button value by clicking, You have to call onselectedindexChanged event for server side where you can actually set the hidden10.Value & if you want to do it client side, you can use Onchange event and select respected data to render the chart

Comment: @m ali:http://jsfiddle.net/zqazf/1/ see this fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:
ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 2 Then
        hidden10.Value = "data2"

Maybe the 2 should be a 3?